# bash: suppress kill message in while loop

Tags: bash

I have a progress bar that prints dots as it waits for an external program to finish executing. When it does finish, I get an ugly kill message which I want to suppress.

```
#!/bin/bash
program < input.file.1 > output.1 &

sim='running simulation'

echo -ne $sim >&2

while kill -0 $!; do

       echo -n . >&2
       sleep 1
done
```

Expected: running simulation.........

Actual: running simulation........./run_with_dots.1: line 8: kill: (11872) - No such process

Comment: BTW, `printf .` is a bit more portable than `echo -n .`; the [POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) leaves the behavior of `echo -n` implementation-defined, and when both `posix` and `xpg_echo` runtime flags are active in bash, `echo -n` emits `-n` and a newline on output.

Comment: Similarly, `printf '%b' "$sim"` is more robust than `echo -ne $sim` (considerably moreso, since `echo -e` is not just implementation-defined but *actively disallowed* from doing anything but printing `-e` on output by the letter of the standard; this is one of the few places where bash's default out-of-the-box behavior *actively breaks* the standard instead of extending it -- but again, with appropriate runtime flags set, that behavior goes away, and `echo -ne` ceases to work... or, by the letter of the standard, starts working correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Redirect stderr:

```
while kill -0 $! 2> /dev/null; do
```